# gdal tool for extracting data

Tags: gdal, netcdf

Is there any gdal tool available for obtaining data from number of files. actually i need  atmospheric parameters which are downloaded from modis website. some datasets are not having data i.e "nodata'. so i have to take previous day's data from database.the files needed are in NETCDf format. i need to check one by one each netcdf file for particular co-ordinate(lat,long) which one is having a value and assign to the variable of the module.can anyone suggest me for obtaining data.

Comment: Are you a python user?

Comment: No. iam using grass but not directly python.